# Adding a text file to an exe generated by PyInstaller

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have a rather interesting problem I've been trying to find a way to solve, and as of the moment, I have not found a solution to. I currently have built a GUI program using Python, and more specifically using Tkinter, which will generate a file with a list of commands to be repeated by my program in the specified order while waiting however long is specified. It's basically used to create a macro, which is recorded in a file and can be ran later using another function in the program.

What I would like to add to my program is a manner in which to create an .exe file, which is a standalone file, that can run a script from within it. The reason I can not find a good way to do this though is because I need for it to be created on the fly. What I was thinking I'd like to do is generate an .exe(Standalone macro exe) with PyInstaller ahead of time, and package this in to my main .exe also using PyInstaller. When you choose the option to create a standalone macro, it would proceed to get the .exe(Standalone macro exe) which I had packaged in to my main .exe from the directory in which it was unpacked in to when the program was run, copy it to the desired location for the standalone exe to be saved to, and then copy the script the user wished to be run as a standalone and package it in to the standalone exe.

I have no idea how to go about this, because I'm not sure exactly how PyInstaller puts the files in to a .exe when it packages it. Because of that, I wouldn't know how to add a file to an existing .exe using python.

Basically what I need help with is how I might go about adding a text file to an .exe generated by PyInstaller.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm,

Could you clarify something...are you thinking something like Perl's (25th birthday today)  (camel book by Larry Wall, p44) handles or a Bash *HERE* document ?

**Update** (based on discussion below): This will integrate python files and other externalities into a single installable:

http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#create-a-spec-file-for-your-project

http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/images/SE_exe.png

Comment: I was thinking something more like Perl's handles, however any solution at all would be more than helpful

Comment: In python, string literals **CAN** span mulitple lines, with a triple quotation mark so _message="""blah   """_

Comment: That's something I could use, but how would I output that in to an .exe? That's what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: If you want to _append_ something, you may be out of luck with python....but take a look here: http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#spec-files

Comment: You might want to examine the '__path__' variable: <br/> <block>Normally, a package's __path__ has only one entry - the directory in which the __init__.py was found. But __init__.py is free to extend its __path__ to include other directories.</block><br/>

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not it can be done in this method. I'm hoping that it can, however if it can't, I'll find a work around using spec files and generating the .exe on the end user's computer when they create choose to create the standalone executable.

Comment: http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#id41

Comment: http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#id46   I think what you are looking for is a **CArchive** !

Comment: I'm still working with CArchive to see if it will fit what I need. With the update you posted, I should mention that that will allow you to pack the file in to your executable, and it will then be extracted to a temporary file when the executable is run, but you may not edit the original file once it is packed.